# Redirect wildcard email accounts

Tags: email, wildcard, forwarding, qmail

I trying to setup a forwarder to forward all the mail send to exapmle*@mydomain.com to myaccount@gmail.com. We are using qmail. I trieed setting ".qmail-example*. But did not work.
can anyone help me on this .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in order to set a forwarder just add an entry at the end in .qmail file of user, which generally is present at users homepath, as:

> &forwarder-id

It works I have been doing for last 10 years now... :-)